# Nested foreach loop to show the data

Tags: laravel, foreach

I have 5 Models `Purchase`, `Inventory`, `Slab`, `Scarting` and `FloorTile`. I'm getting the collection from `Purchase` model, then from that collection i'm fetching data from `Inventory` table. Then depending on that data i going to further model `Slab` which has relation with `Inventory`. Now after getting data from the `Slab` model i want to show that on blade using `Foreach` loop. But i'm getting error:

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I've tried this in my Controller:

`$slabs = Purchase::where('factoryName', $factoryName)->with('inventory.slab')->get();`

This Query result is as follows:

```
{
    "id": 36,
    "marbleType_id": 2,
    "fname": "Sama",
    "lname": "Jojo",
    "factoryName": "Sama Inc.",
    "cnic": "3216542",
    "area": "Johar town",
    "city": "Lahore",
    "province": "Punjab",
    "phone1": "45678912345",
    "phone2": "45678912345",
    "inventory_ID": 10,
    "created_at": "2019-03-19 12:11:45",
    "updated_at": "2019-03-19 12:11:45",
        "inventory": {
        "id": 10,
        "purchase_id": 36,
        "marbleType": "1",
        "totalSquareFt": 25,
        "priceperSquareFt": 230,
        "totalPurchasePrice": 25000,
        "standardSize_ID": "5",
        "salePrice": 250,
        "miliMeter": "6mm",
        "slab_ID": 1,
        "scarting_ID": null,
        "floorTile_ID": null,
        "created_at": "2019-03-19 12:11:45",
        "updated_at": "2019-03-19 12:11:45",
            "slab": {
             "id": 1,
             "marbleName_ID": "2",
             "inventory_ID": "10",
             "created_at": "2019-03-19 12:11:45",
             "updated_at": "2019-03-19 12:11:45"
             }
        }
},
{
    "id": 55,
    "marbleType_id": 3,
    "fname": "Sama",
    "lname": "Jojo",
    "factoryName": "Sama Inc.",
    "cnic": "32165421",
    "area": "Johar town",
    "city": "Lahore",
    "province": "Punjab",
    "phone1": "45678912345",
    "phone2": "45678912345",
    "inventory_ID": 26,
    "created_at": "2019-04-25 10:47:41",
    "updated_at": "2019-04-25 10:47:41",
        "inventory": {
        "id": 26,
        "purchase_id": 55,
        "marbleType": "1",
        "totalSquareFt": 12,
        "priceperSquareFt": 12,
        "totalPurchasePrice": 120,
        "standardSize_ID": "1",
        "salePrice": 15,
        "miliMeter": "6mm",
        "slab_ID": 9,
        "scarting_ID": null,
        "floorTile_ID": null,
        "created_at": "2019-04-25 10:47:41",
        "updated_at": "2019-04-25 10:47:41",
            "slab": {
            "id": 9,
            "marbleName_ID": "3",
            "inventory_ID": "26",
            "created_at": "2019-04-25 10:47:41",
            "updated_at": "2019-04-25 10:47:41"
            }
        }
},
{
    "id": 56,
    "marbleType_id": 4,
    "fname": "Sama",
    "lname": "Jojo",
    "factoryName": "Sama Inc.",
    "cnic": null,
    "area": "Johar town",
    "city": "Lahore",
    "province": "Punjab",
    "phone1": "45678912345",
    "phone2": "45678912345",
    "inventory_ID": 27,
    "created_at": "2019-05-05 20:11:52",
    "updated_at": "2019-05-05 20:11:52",
        "inventory": {
        "id": 27,
        "purchase_id": 56,
        "marbleType": "3",
        "totalSquareFt": 20,
        "priceperSquareFt": 20,
        "totalPurchasePrice": 420,
        "standardSize_ID": "3",
        "salePrice": 25,
        "miliMeter": "6mm",
        "slab_ID": null,
        "scarting_ID": null,
        "floorTile_ID": 10,
        "created_at": "2019-05-05 20:11:52",
        "updated_at": "2019-05-05 20:11:52",
        "slab": null
        }
},
{
    "id": 57,
    "marbleType_id": 9,
    "fname": "Sama",
    "lname": "Jojo",
    "factoryName": "Sama Inc.",
    "cnic": null,
    "area": "Johar town",
    "city": "Lahore",
    "province": "Punjab",
    "phone1": "45678912345",
    "phone2": "45678912345",
    "inventory_ID": 28,
    "created_at": "2019-05-05 20:32:41",
    "updated_at": "2019-05-05 20:32:41",
        "inventory": {
        "id": 28,
        "purchase_id": 57,
        "marbleType": "2",
        "totalSquareFt": 31,
        "priceperSquareFt": 12,
        "totalPurchasePrice": 400,
        "standardSize_ID": "1",
        "salePrice": 15,
        "miliMeter": "8mm",
        "slab_ID": null,
        "scarting_ID": 4,
        "floorTile_ID": null,
        "created_at": "2019-05-05 20:32:41",
        "updated_at": "2019-05-05 20:32:42",
        "slab": null
        }
},
{
    "id": 59,
    "marbleType_id": 12,
    "fname": "Sama",
    "lname": "Jojo",
    "factoryName": "Sama Inc.",
    "cnic": null,
    "area": "Johar town",
    "city": "Lahore",
    "province": "Punjab",
    "phone1": "12345678945",
    "phone2": "45678945645",
    "inventory_ID": 30,
    "created_at": "2019-05-06 10:14:35",
    "updated_at": "2019-05-06 10:14:35",
        "inventory": {
        "id": 30,
        "purchase_id": 59,
        "marbleType": "2",
        "totalSquareFt": 12,
        "priceperSquareFt": 12,
        "totalPurchasePrice": 122,
        "standardSize_ID": "1",
        "salePrice": 12,
        "miliMeter": "8mm",
        "slab_ID": null,
        "scarting_ID": 5,
        "floorTile_ID": null,
        "created_at": "2019-05-06 10:14:35",
        "updated_at": "2019-05-06 10:14:35",
        "slab": null
        }
}
```

Here is the Foreach loop in the controller to get data only related to `Slab`.

```
foreach ($slabs as $slab) {
   if ($slab->inventory->slab_ID != NULL) {
       $marble_id = $slab->inventory->slab->marbleName_ID;
       $slab->marble = MarbleType::where('id', $marble_id)->get();
   }
}
```

And here is the blade content where I want to show `Slab`'s data in the table.

```
@foreach($slabs  as $slab)
    @foreach($slab->marble as $mar)
        <tr>
            @if($slab->inventory->marbleType == 1)
               <td> Slab </td>
            @endif
            <td>{{ $mar->marbleType }}</td>
            <td>{{ $slab->inventory->totalSquareFt }}</td>
            <td>{{ $slab->inventory->totalPurchasePrice }}</td>
            <td>{{ date('M j, Y h:ia' , strtotime( $slab->created_at )) }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach    
@endforeach
```

This the error i'm getting on the blade file:
`Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Can anyone point out what i'm doing wrong.?

Comment: one of the `$slab->marble` and `$slabs` or both are not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need an `else` statement on your `$slab->inventory->slab_ID` check, otherwise, you'll be trying to loop `null` (`$slab->marble` will equate to `null`). If you did `else { $slab->marble = []; }`, then you'd be able to use that `foreach` without worry code.

```
foreach ($slabs as $slab) {
  if ($slab->inventory->slab_ID != NULL) {
    $marble_id = $slab->inventory->slab->marbleName_ID;
    $slab->marble = MarbleType::where('id', $marble_id)->get();
  } else {
    $slab->marble = [];
  }

  foreach($slab->marble AS $mar){
    ...
  }
}
```

Sidenote, this code is likely very inefficient. Anytime you need to run a query in a loop, you face the potential for a bottleneck. Consider using a relationship and eager loading that in your initial query.

Also sidenote, if `$slab->inventory` is `null`, you'll run into a `trying to get property of non-object` error when using `$slab->inventory->slab_ID`.

Comment: You're using it already; `->with('inventory.slab')` is an example. If you didn't call that, when you accessed `purchase->inventory`, and `inventory->slab`, those would execute a new query, using resources. But since you did use `->with()`, it would be loaded already, so accessing doesn't call a new query.

Comment: And what was about "The code is likely very inefficient"..?? Infact i'm new to laravel so i don't know much about coding standards. I would appreciate if u could guide me properly. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah, no worries. So when running a loop, if you perform a query in that loop, it has to reach out to the database `n` times to get that data. This can be very inefficient depending on how large that loop is. What eager loading does is makes the initial query a little more resource-heavy, but prevents you having to perform queries in a loop thereafter. Its all a little broad, and something you'll figure out in time.

Comment: I need to ask u something like what if I want not to repeat Specific `$mar->marbleType` in the table, but i want to add attribute values(i.e. `totalSquareFt`, `totalPurchasePrice`) of that specific `marbleType` to the old identical `Marble` ... Can you please tell me how it could be done.?

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question. Comments are for clarification/additional information, not new questions altogether. I'm not too sure what you're asking either, so best to open a new question with more information/practical examples.

Comment: Ok i understand. I've posted new question but nobody answered yet :( its been 6 hours.